# How to set Session ID in the authorisation Header using Named credentials Salesforce

Tags: apex, callout

I am trying to make REST Tooling API callout and I want to send Session id in the Authorisation Header. Thru apex we can send the Session ID in the Header but if I use Named credentials to store the endpoint , then how can I set Session ID in the authorisation Header using Named Credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you authenticated the Named Credentials with OAuth, you can simply check the "Generate Authentication Header" checkbox on the Named Credential, and it will automatically generate it for you.

You can also use the "Allow Merge Fields in Header" option, and use this in your code:

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', '{!$Credential.AuthorizationHeaderValue}');
```

Otherwise, if you don't use that method, you can use the original method for using the Authorization header, namely:

```
res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

Or, if you've obtained a session Id by some other means, you can do that as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.